# How do I remove an interface from a virtual host on ganeti?

Tags: ganeti

I added a second interface to a virtual host by mistake, and now I want to remove it. I couldn't find a command to do it, though. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, just reverse the command to add the interface:

```
gnt-instance modify --net remove:ip=a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to remove it from the un-answered queue. Thanks :)

Comment: @AliGibbs Alas, I can only do so after 48 hours. Not my rules... But it would be removed from that queue if it were to be _upvoted_.